# expandable tabelview section in swift

Tags: swift

hey there I'm working on an app where I have a tableview which has sections with custom cells.
so my task is to show the cells when clicked on section and hide when clicked again.
I don't know what to write in the didselect method of tableview

Comment: `.. my task is to show the cells when clicked on section ..` section is just "group" of rows(cells). Do you mean when tap on cell or you have header for each section?

Answer (score -1):

You could *hide* cell simply by deleting all the cell of the section. For exemple, I add a button in my header view that trigger this function that will delete all the cell of the current section :

```
 func toggleView() {
    // SHOW
    if toggleStatut == false {
        toggleStatut = true
        // Get indexPath of my element in my second section
        var indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
        indexPaths = indexPaths?.filter({ (indexPath) -> Bool in
            return indexPath.section == 1
        })
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths ?? [], with: .fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    } 
    // HIDE
    else {
        toggleStatut = false
        let indexPaths = (0..<elements.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 1) }
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths , with: .fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

    }
}
```

So no need to use the `didSelect` method. Instead you could add a protocol that your header will implement to call the above function